# ./run_timer.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, sh, executable-jar, putty

I'm delevoping a TV Scoreboard Application by using window laptop and raspberry pi.
Socket connection by Putty.I have put the script timer.sh inside the raspberry pi by using WinSCP.

But when i run the command:

```
./run_timer.sh
```

Error prompt:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ./run_timer.sh
-bash: ./run_timer.sh: No such file or directory
```

timer.sh with command:

```
#!/bin/sh

java -jar /home/pi/ScoreBoard_app/Timer/Timer.jar
```

Any step i missed?

Comment: Can you please put the content of your directory with `ls -la`? If the file exists the problem lies elsewhere in either your Java installation (where did you compiled that `Timer.jar`? For which target?) or some missing libraries.

Comment: I am not really understand why it is needed me to set the X11 server variable. But the one in-charge this project before can straight run the java scoreboard application and remote to the TV by raspberry pi without connect to X server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that the script, run_time.sh, is missing. I think your script's name should be timer.sh and there is nothing about the content of script. Make sure there is run_timer.sh in current directory.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I see. Because the project firstly is not in-charged by me. And there is missing sh file inside the raspberry pi but with the remote command. So, i just make a new one and named as timer.sh. Thank you.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Learning bash and Linux is helpful for you and I hope you could keep working hard.